# Jquery / Phonegap / IOS - sound reaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

We have a client who has asked us to build an app for a music artist (in a short period of time) - generally basic stuff - other that one feature...

They would like it to be able to 'listen' and detect between certain songs at a concert so that we it can trigger a jQuery/Javascript function that would make the phone display a certain colour during a certain song.  It doesn't have to actually detect the song - the BPM would possibly surfice.

To add to the complication I am a front-end developer - so the app would need to be HTML5 and written using Phonegap, the app needs to be IOS.

I have no idea how to approach this or whether its even possible - but if anyone has any ideas - please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing BPM Analysis with Web Tools sounds pretty scary...
Have a look at this library: https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/ and this here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/beatdetektor/
Not sure if you can do this in real time though